# Pandas: How to merge two dataframes on two different overlapping timeseries

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, time-series

I have created two dataframes, both covering the whole year of 2012 with datetime as overlapping columns.
df1 rows/samples are in milliseconds and df2 has a row for each 15 min.
They obviously overlap, but how do I get them to merge where the df2 rows get inserted into DF1 based on Time.
I have tried merging on outer, which should the be the right choice, but I have also tried "inner", "left" and even "right".

It will add the columns from df2 but doesn't seem to add the rows from df2
I have only added a sample of my dataset as df1 has over 100 million samples.
Here are csv's with 10.000:
[df1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uSqPqo4BjLY8Ts6is6ifsJN2TgCmnGcT/view?usp=sharing)
[df2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19s-9k2FjdMGij0bNXtvFmbNKo1h3gfSA/view?usp=sharing)
Help will be much appreciated :-)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def mergeDF(lowTF,highTF):
    tf_merge = pd.merge(lowTF, highTF, on='Time', how='outer')
    fill_merge = tf_merge.fillna(method='ffill')
    return fill_merge
```

**df1:**

```
Time,Year,Month,Day,Hour
2012-01-09 00:00:00.653,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:01.388,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:01.739,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:02.265,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:03.349,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:03.489,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:04.311,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:04.719,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:05.384,2012,1,9,0
2012-01-09 00:00:05.800,2012,1,9,0
```

**df2:**

```
Time,DayOfWeak,ext_Volume,15_Absorption Volume,15_Bag Holding
2012-01-09 00:00:00,1,679,0,0
2012-01-09 00:15:00,1,988,0,0
2012-01-09 00:30:00,1,718,0,0
2012-01-09 00:45:00,1,583,0,0
2012-01-09 01:00:00,1,885,0,0
2012-01-09 01:15:00,1,589,0,0
2012-01-09 01:30:00,1,611,0,0
2012-01-09 01:45:00,1,620,0,0
2012-01-09 02:00:00,1,657,0,0
2012-01-09 02:15:00,1,691,0,0
```

-

```
merged = mergeDF(df1,df2)
merged

Time,Year,Month,Day,Hour,DayOfWeak,ext_Volume,15_Absorption Volume,15_Bag Holding
2012-01-09 00:00:00.653,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:01.388,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:01.739,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:02.265,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:03.349,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:03.489,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:04.311,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:04.719,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:05.384,2012,1,9,0,,,,
2012-01-09 00:00:05.800,2012,1,9,0,,,,
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide a reproducible example? Take a quick look on [how to make good pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the most intuitive way is:

```
pd.merge_asof(DF1, DF2, on='Time')
```

To present a more instructive example, I changed the *minute* in last
two rows in *DF1* to *15* and got:

```
                     Time  Year  Month  Day  Volume  DayOfWeek_x  ext_Volume  15_Absorption Volume
0 2012-01-09 00:00:00.653  2012      1    9       3            1         679                     0
1 2012-01-09 00:00:01.388  2012      1    9       2            1         679                     0
2 2012-01-09 00:00:01.739  2012      1    9       2            1         679                     0
3 2012-01-09 00:15:02.265  2012      1    9       2            1         988                     0
4 2012-01-09 00:15:03.349  2012      1    9       2            1         988                     0
```

As you can see, rows with indices *0*, *1* and *2* where merged with
*Time* == *00:00:00*, whereas the last 2 with *Time* == *00:15:00*,
what is easy to verify on *ext_Volume* column.

Comment: Thank you Valdi_Bo. It worked perfectly and it even made the .fillna code redundant as the values were copied to the other rows.